# How do you combine multiple gpu's together so they have a cumulative power?

Tags: gpu, pci

I was wondering about the possibility of there being a type of software/hardware or just a basic computer function that would allow multiple gpu's to work together when they are separately connected in different PCI slots? My main purpose for this function is using multiple gpu's in Blender rendering.

Comment: You might get a better response on [Superuser SE](https://superuser.com)

Comment: If you google "blender use multiple gpus" you get your answer. Also links like SLI exists since 2000's. The main problem is transferring data and configuration between the CPU, other than that it's just like having half the work.